# Is @responsebody required even when using the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jackson

I was reading this https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ and I see that in Spring 4 , the `@RestController` is a combination of `@ResponseBody` and `@Controller` and hence its not necessary to mention the `@ResponseBody` at every method as it was previously. But, in one of the application am working on, we are using Spring 3.x and we have developed spring webservices and annotated the Controller class as `@Controller`. The sample controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class SomeController {

@RequestMapping(value = "uri/{values}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<SampleClassPOJO> giveSomething(@PathVariable("values") String some){

//logic

return listOfSampleClassPOJO;

}

//Other services

}
```

and have the following config in the dispatcher servlet xml :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="prettyPrint" value="false"/>                        
                <property name="objectMapper">
                    <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper"/>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The dispatcher servlet is referred in the web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>someCustom.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatch</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And we haven't annotated with `@ResponseBody` for any of the web services method nor at the class level, but still the response is a json. So, when is the `@ResponseBody` annotation required?

Now, this has gotten me into a confused state, I tried to search for any example with just the above entry in the dispatcher-servlet.xml and **without using the `@ResponseBody`** in the methods of the services, but there **are no example** as such. Only thing I found was, the above entry along with `@RestController` annotation in Spring 4.

Can anyone please tell me what is the piece of information that am missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of a snippet add configuration and code to have a complete picture. Also which Spring 3.x version are you exactly using, and do you also have a `<mvc:annotation-driven />` and in which configuration file this `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` is being configured. There are a lot of moving components here and depending on what you use and configure where the result might differ. Hence currently there is too little information to answer your question.

Comment: Hi, we are using Spring 3.1 version , and have defined <context:annotation-config/> in the application-context.xml . The above xml snippet which I have mentioned is in the dispatcher-servlet.xml and which has been configured in the web.xml . Is there anything else that is required?

Comment: It is still to fragmented... also I nowhere mentioned `<context:annotation-config />` but I mentioned `<mvc:annotation-driven />`. Add your web.xml and `dispatcher-servlet.xml` to your question. As mentioned the full picture is needed not just fragments.

Comment: is the recent edit better?

Comment: Slightly but I still have no idea on what is configured, as you don't show the full configuration. For all its worth the definition you posted could be worthless due to some other configuration setup.

Comment: Hi, am not sure what else is required. Let us keep this simple. If I try to build web services as it is tried here : https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ , they have used @RestController . My question is, can I use just the Controller annotation with the org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter in the classpath without using the ResponseBody annotation to automatically convert Objects to json as a response?  does my question makes sense? Or.. ?

Comment: The fact that `@ResponseBody` is or isn't required depends on what you have configured. Without seeing your configuration I cannot determine WHAT you have configured and cannot provide you with an answer. So currently your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118215/discussion-between-h-kach-and-m-deinum).